# ComboBoxes not getting populated from stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, combobox, populate

I want to populate a ComboBox on a form.  I have stored procedures that get the data for my ComboBoxes.  My code is below.  The problem is my comboboxes don't get populated.  When I step through the code, it gets to the "reader = sc.ExecuteReader();" line and does not execute any of the subsequent lines in Pop_ComboBox().  The stored procedure returns "ID" and "Description" (only).  What am I doing wrong?

```
    private void frmInput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Connect to the db
        this.sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=\"our_server";Database=\"Astra\";Trusted_Connection=yes;");

        //Populate the Equipment Type Listbox
        Pop_ComboBox("exec uspASTRA_GetEquipTypeList;", cboEquipType);


    }

    private void Pop_ComboBox(string sQuery, ComboBox NameOfcbo)
    {
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(sQuery, this.sqlConn);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);

        NameOfcbo.ValueMember = "ID";
        NameOfcbo.DisplayMember = "Description";
        NameOfcbo.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Comment: You're probably getting an exception on the call to `ExecuteReader`. Inside Visual Studio, go to `Debug->Exceptions`, check everything and debug again. Or put the call in a try-catch block and look at the exception.

Comment: You have not opened your connection by the way ... !! this.sqlConn.Open();

Comment: @Azhar - Thank you for catching that! And thanks to dario for the suggestion.  I see now that My SqlConn isn't working right.

Comment: It is working now.  Dario's suggestion of putting the code in a try-catch block helped solve it.  It turns out I had no connection to the db.  I'm used to VB which stops code execution when an exception occurs in debug mode.  Now I know I need try catch blocks everywhere while debugging in C#.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wanted to sum this up into a cogent answer to my own question.  I need to give credit where it is due, however, because I could not be answering were it not for some great thoughts from others.

First of all, I needed a Try-Catch block around my code.  If I'd had that, I would have gotten the information that I did not have a good connection to the db.  Thank you Dario-Ramos!

Second, I needed a good connection string and to explicitly connect to the db.  Obviously.  Thank you, Azhar Khorasany!

Finally, as suggested by Eslam Gamal, I needed to set the command type to "stored procedure," and execute as follows:

```
sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataReader dr = sc.ExecuteReader();
```

Thank you all for your suggestions.  I learned some valuable lessons and my combo boxes get populated!

Answer (score 1):

Use a SqlDataAdapter and fill your datatable. e.g:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

Then bind your combo boxes datasource with datatable.

Comment: I'm curious:  Why is a DataAdapter better than a DataReader for a read-only dataset?  Or are you making the suggestion because a datareader cannot be used as I am trying to use it?

Comment: Now that I have a good connection to the db, my original code (using a SqlDataReader) works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the command type to StoredProcedure

```
sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and dont Use `exec` just use the StoredProc name